# I installed Yarn on a project that used npm and now I can't install a library

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, chainlink, hardhat

I'm working with a blockchain project using hardhat and I wanted to install the chainlink contracts library. After mistakenly installing Yarn (I'm new to both), I cannot go back to using NPM and installing with Yarn is also not successful.

I tried Stack Overflow suggestions and the deyarn tool and trying to force use of NPM as per https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-force-use-yarn-or-npm/

I added an `.npmrc` file with

```
//.npmrc file

engine-strict = true
```

and added the line below in `package.json`:

```
"engines": {
    "yarn": "YARN NO LONGER USED - use npm instead.",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  }
```

I have copied the original error message below when using NPM (that would be my preferred package manager):

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Programming\epic-game-v2\node_modules\@chainlink\contracts
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node -e "if(process.env.npm_execpath.indexOf('yarn') === -1) throw new Error('Please use yarn to install dependencies\n\n')"
npm ERR! [eval]:1
npm ERR! if(process.env.npm_execpath.indexOf('yarn') === -1) throw new Error('Please use yarn to install dependencies\n\n')
npm ERR!                                                     ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Please use yarn to install dependencies
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at [eval]:1:59
npm ERR!     at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:129:12)
npm ERR!     at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:305:38)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/process/execution:81:19
npm ERR!     at [eval]-wrapper:6:22
npm ERR!     at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:80:60)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/eval_string:27:3
```

Comment: Evidently one of your dependencies is trying to force Yarn as you're trying to force NPM. You can't both win.

Comment: Yes, reinstalled everything using yarn and it all works now.